# Pandas Grouping and getting an average on a specific column while taking the row with the max value of a specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'text': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'],
    'group': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    'value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'some_other_to_include': ['a', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'b'],
    'criticality': [3, 3, 5, 4, 4]
})
```

Where i want to group by the 'group' column, then take an average of the value column while selecting the row with the highest 'criticality' and keeping the other columns

Intended result:

```
text    group    value    some_other_to_include    criticality
a       1        2        c                        5
b       2        4.5      b                        4
```

But i can't figure out a way without building a new dataframe from scratch and using nlargest and avg.
Is there a smarter way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for get indices by maximal `criticality` with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select all columns, last change column `value` by aggregate `mean` in [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
g = df.groupby('group')

out = (df.loc[g['criticality'].idxmax()]
         .assign(value=lambda x: x['group'].map(g['value'].mean())))
print (out)
  text  group  value some_other_to_include  criticality
2    a      1    2.0                     c            5
3    b      2    4.5                     b            4
```

or in [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
g = df.groupby('group')

out = (df.loc[g['criticality'].idxmax()]
         .drop('value', axis=1).join(g['value'].mean(), on='group')[df.columns])

print (out)
  text  group  value some_other_to_include  criticality
2    a      1    2.0                     c            5
3    b      2    4.5                     b            4
```